# MacOS Chrome Body Styling Bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I started working on a web design project recently and ran into several issues with body styling in **Chrome Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build)**. I have asked 2 other people I know to replicate this issue and they were both able to via a hosted site on c9, as well as locally with the same Chrome Version as I had. This does not occur in any other browser, or OS that I have tested on. (Firefox, Firefox Developer Edition, Safari, Windows Chrome). At this point, it's a game of chance. 50% of the time the background image loads onpageload, 50% of the time it doesn't.

Adding a `background: url('') ...`, `background-color: ...`, or `background-image: url('') ...` to the `<body></body>` tag works fine *until* I add an `<input>` field on the page. Once added, the body styling completely disappears and only re-appears when I select the input field. The same occurs with a `submit` button for the form, the styling only appears on the body if I select the Submit button.

Adding styling to the `html` tag seemed to solve this issue, and so did adding a full-page content wrapper immediately after the opening `<body>` tag and styling that. **The conclusion I came up with is that This particular Chrome version for MacOS has one or more bugs and cannot properly style the body tag consistently, however I find this hard to believe for several reasons.** 1) No other browser has this issue, 2) I've found a *few* similar posts about a similar issue on body styling dating back at most 7 years, and 3) Out of thousands and thousands of sites I've visited on this particular Chrome Version, I can not recall a single one of them ever having messed up styling. This makes me think that either my HTML/CSS is somehow messed up, even though I haven't encountered this issue in several years of web design, or I somehow missed the Web Design PSA that Chrome for MacOS randomly broke one day and everyone should style their `HTML` tag or create a separate wrapper.

I've searched a lot for this and haven't been able to find any official or unofficial posts regarding this particular issue, so if someone has some insight into this I would very greatly appreciate it.

If you do not want to test locally, I have a hosted site on c9.io you can view, although it may not be up 100% of the time.

I have tried alternate solutions in the css as well, such as putting `full/path/to/image/.png` instead of `../`, and setting a fixed background color, and neither appear to be a solution.

*I have also tried various reset.css files, and no reset at all, and the issue is still present*

c9: https://chrome-issue-slooth(dot)c9users(dot)io/index.html
Some code to test locally:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/app.css">
    <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="register-block">
            <!-- Left Block -->
            <div class="rb-left">
                <!-- Form Wrapper -->
                <div class="form-wrap">
                    <!-- Signup Form -->
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        <!-- Label -->
                        <p class="signup-label">SIGN UP FORM</p>
                        <!-- Form input Username -->
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="usernameField" placeholder="Username">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- Bottom Block -->
                <div class="rb-bottom">
                    <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Right Block -->
            <div class="rb-right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

^ This paired with the following css reproduces the error:

```
            /* normalize.css */            
            /* <snippet> */
            /* end of normalize.css */

    ul {
      -webkit-padding-start: 0px; }

    li {
      list-style: none; }

    p {
      margin: 0px; }

    body {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/lNjufWn.png");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat; }
      body .register-block {
        background: #233A48; }
        body .register-block .rb-left .form-wrap {
          padding: 45px 80px; }
        body .register-block .rb-left .rb-bottom {
          background: #1E323E;
          padding: 18px 0px; }
          body .register-block .rb-left .rb-bottom p a {
            display: inline-block; }
```

Adding the following snippet of CSS is one solution I have found:

```
html, body {
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/lNjufWn.png");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Comment: So what's the question? Report this to the Chrome team over [here](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/).

Comment: I've planned on submitted a bug report, but wanted to see if other people experienced this. In fact, one of the first things stated on Google's page about [How to file a Good Bug](https://developers.google.com/web/feedback/file-a-bug) it to see if others are experiencing this issue. The last thing I want to do is submit a bug report that myself and 2 other people experience without knowing whether or not other people experience it or are affected by it.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, and have actually noticed it as well on my own webapp. Please report this!

Comment: Also, I'm running Linux (for the bug report)